# Understanding autoload and spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I have a small framerwork and in my scripts I use autoload (I just now aware that I need to start getting rid of this function in my scripts)

I am now trying to use the Twilio API, in their code, they use the spl_autoload_register function.  After the logic block that the twilio code is called in the rest of the script breaks down when I make a new call to one of my classes

my file structure is this

```
/classes/
    autoload.php
    DB_Connect.php

/classes/Twilio/

/sms/Twilio/Services/
    twilo.php
```

The script that is breaking down looks something like this

```
<?php 

include(classes/autoload.php);

if($something_is_true){
    requrie_once(sms/Twilio/Services/Twilio.php);
    //here is where the spl_autoload_register() is called
}

$connection = new DB_Connect();
//script is broken here
```

What do I need to do now in the Classes folder to make all of the classes work?

Answer (score 3):

The reason probably is that your autoloader [(`__autoload()`) gets completely replaced once `spl_autoload_register()` is called](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php):

> If your code has an existing __autoload() function then this function must be explicitly registered on the __autoload stack. This is because spl_autoload_register() will effectively replace the engine cache for the __autoload() function by either spl_autoload() or spl_autoload_call().

You can update your script to work within seconds, as only a slight change is needed to properly register your autoloader.

Currently it looks like this:

```
function __autoload($class) {
    // ...
}
```

Change it like this (assuming you are running PHP 5.3):

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    // ...
});
```

Before PHP 5.3 adding this should work as well:

```
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

Comment: +1 `The reason probably is that your autoloader gets completely replaced once` - that is such important part that I have missed looking at the PHP Manual!!